# large list of strings should be impossible

Tags: c#, string, list, compression

I have run code in a C# console app that stores a list of strings. the objective of this code is to create the largest collection of the string "q" as possible in 1 second. It is simply an exercise in my programming ability and has no practical application.

When I run this code it stops itself in exactly 1 second, and when I count up all the "q"'s in all the strings I get 214,870,505,313,584 which is in the hundreds of trillions. The char "q" takes up a byte and if this thing has 200 trillion bytes it means the list of strings is over 2 terabytes.

How is this possible, is there some sort of auto compression going on? is there a way to turn it off?

Here is the code if you want.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleAppWebScrape
{
    class Program
    {
        //the origional string
        static string l = "q";
        static DateTime d;
        static List<string> output = new List<string>();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //hit enter to start
            Console.Read();
            d = DateTime.Now;

            //start the string doubling thread
            Thread thred2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(doubleL));
            thred2.Start();
            //start the write to list thread                                                                                               
            Thread thred1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(writeToFile));
            thred1.Start();

            while (haveTime())
            {
               //pause current thread for the remander of the second. 
            }

            long lo = howmany();

            Console.WriteLine(lo);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        //determines the amount of "q"s in the list of strings
        static long howmany()
        {
            long lo = 0;
            foreach (string s in output)
            {
                lo += s.Length;
            }
            return lo;
        }
        //writes to the list of strings.
        static void writeToFile()
        {
            while (haveTime())
            {
                output.Add(l);
            }
        }
        //builds a string by doubling the origional string
        static bool tobig = false;
        static void doubleL()
        {
            while (haveTime() && !tobig)
            {
                if (l.Length < 268435456)
                {
                    l = l + l;
                }
                else
                {
                    tobig = true;
                }
            }
        }
        //bool to determin if it is running inside one second
        static bool haveTime()
        {
            if ((DateTime.Now - d).TotalSeconds < 1)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are summing the length of the strings, not the amount of q's.

Comment: you keep adding the same string. if you would use `output.Add("q");` instead of `output.Add(l);` I think you would encounter an out of memory exception.

Comment: @ZoharPeled That wouldn't change a thing.  Your code would still be adding the same string over and over again.

Comment: @Servy what if it was `output.Add(new string("q"));`? same thing?

Comment: Also, the `char` "q" does not take up one byte - in .NET `strings` are UTF-16, meaning they either take two bytes per character, or four bytes for certain characters (Unicode U+10000 to U+10FFFF). The character `q` is represented as two bytes.

Comment: @ZoharPeled That just wouldn't compile.

Comment: @Servy ok, `new String('q')`, the point was to ask of you have 2 different string variables with the same content are they both referencing the same string or is there a different string for each of them. the exact constructor is irrelevant to the comment.

Comment: @ZoharPeled It is possible to construct strings that are equal but not reference equal, yes.

Comment: So, if it's `output.Add(new string('q'));`, wouldn't that be adding different strings that happens to have the same value?

Comment: Good read here about string interning https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've read a while back that strings are stored on the heap and referenced. Since it's the same character over and over again, you're probably creating trillions of references to the same physical address.

Comment: Correct. You are adding the reference to the same string to the list in the first thread over and over again, up until the second thread changes the string, then the first thread ads a new reference and so on. So in your list you have X references to "q", Y references to "qq" and so on. (X and Y may be very large, and they will get larger over time because it will take more time to double the string than to add a reference to the list)

Comment: @DenisYarkovoy The lack of proper synchronization means that the main thread won't actually be reflecting the updates of the second thread nearly as often as you might expect it to be either, meaning that there'll be a lot more copies of the same strings than there would be if there was proper synchronization.